# IS 2C10 a valid UTF-8 character?

Tags: xml, unicode, utf-8, sax, saxparser

I'm running some XML through a SAX parser and have noticed the parser is not functioning correctly with certain characters as data content.
The XML is supposed to be in UTF-8 encoding and the SAX parser is set to process that encoding.

Narrowing down problematic strings and looking at the XML file in a hex editor I can see for example that 2C10 causes a problem, if I change this instead to C2A2 (an example character given on wikipedia) then the SAX parser works. So is 2C10 not a valid UTF8 character?

Comment: How can 2C10 be both a control character and a Glagolitic character? Isn't it one or the other? If it can be both depending upon something, what is that something? How does a utf8 parser know what to do with it? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

U+2C10 is `GLAGOLITIC CAPITAL LETTER NASHI`.  Here are its properties:

```
U+2C10 ‹Ⱀ› \N{GLAGOLITIC CAPITAL LETTER NASHI}
\w \pL \p{LC} \p{L_} \p{L&} \p{Lu}
All Any Alnum Alpha Alphabetic Assigned InGlagolitic Glagolitic
   Is_Glagolitic Cased Cased_Letter LC Changes_When_Casefolded
   CWCF Changes_When_Casemapped CWCM Changes_When_Lowercased
   CWL Changes_When_NFKC_Casefolded CWKCF Lu L Glag Gr_Base
   Grapheme_Base Graph GrBase ID_Continue IDC ID_Start IDS
   Letter L_ Uppercase_Letter Print Upper Uppercase Word
   XID_Continue XIDC XID_Start XIDS X_POSIX_Alnum X_POSIX_Alpha
   X_POSIX_Graph X_POSIX_Print X_POSIX_Upper X_POSIX_Word
Age=4.1 Bidi_Class=L Bidi_Class=Left_To_Right BC=L
   Block=Glagolitic Canonical_Combining_Class=0
   Canonical_Combining_Class=Not_Reordered CCC=NR
   Canonical_Combining_Class=NR General_Category=Cased_Letter
   Decomposition_Type=None DT=None East_Asian_Width=Neutral
   GC=LC General_Category=L General_Category=Letter
   General_Category=L_ General_Category=LC GC=L
   General_Category=Lu General_Category=Uppercase_Letter GC=Lu
   Script=Glagolitic Grapheme_Cluster_Break=Other GCB=XX
   Grapheme_Cluster_Break=XX Hangul_Syllable_Type=NA
   Hangul_Syllable_Type=Not_Applicable HST=NA
   Joining_Group=No_Joining_Group JG=NoJoiningGroup
   Joining_Type=Non_Joining JT=U Joining_Type=U Line_Break=AL
   Line_Break=Alphabetic LB=AL Numeric_Type=None NT=None
   Numeric_Value=NaN NV=NaN Present_In=4.1 IN=4.1
   Present_In=5.0 IN=5.0 Present_In=5.1 IN=5.1 Present_In=5.2
   IN=5.2 Present_In=6.0 IN=6.0 Script=Glag SC=Glag
   Sentence_Break=UP Sentence_Break=Upper SB=UP
   Word_Break=ALetter WB=LE Word_Break=LE _X_Begin
```

Comment: Presumably an XML parser which can deal with utf-8 should be able to deal with this then, otherwise its a bug?

Comment: @Teres: That depends on whether you are talking about  byte sequences or  abstract characters.  U+2C10 is an abstract Unicode code point as already described.  A byte with hex value `"\x2C"` followed by one with the value `"\x10"` **when decoded from UTF‑8** is the abstract Unicode codepoint U+002C COMMA followed by the abstract Unicode code point U+0010 DATA LINK ESCAPE. The abstact Unicode code point U+2C10 **when encoded into UTF‑8** produces the three bytes `"\xE2\xB0\x90"`.

Comment: Byte sequences already in utf-8. When I look at a part of the XML file being parsed which causes a problem in a hex editor I see ... 3E 2C 10 3C ... ( including the preceding '>' and following '<' characters).

Comment: @Teres: Ah then. It is a control character then.

Answer (score 0):

The [UTF-8 page on Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8#Codepage_layout) implies that 2C10 is to be interpreted as `,` followed by the control code `DLE` (data link escape, apparently).  A control character appearing outside of a CDATA block in XML would seem inappropriate!

Comment: So the answer is that it is valid UTF-8, but that the codepoint U+0010 is not allowed in an XML document (although it is allowed as a character entity reference in XML 1.1).